# Texture Bake Return Value

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to print to the console when the texture bake is finished, using this line of code:

> bpy.ops.object.bake()

Is there a return value for this, like if it is canceled or when it's finished? Maybe about the current status, like what % it's on?

Comment: Doesn't it block until the bake is done?

Comment: If you're talking about the UI getting unresponsive during the bake, no it's not, if I use the INVOKE_DEFAULT argument.

Comment: You can check if a bake is running with `bpy.app.is_job_running('OBJECT_BAKE')` but I don't know how to get more detailed status info.

Comment: that's good info, didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: useful page to learn how to launch a recurring function to check `is_job_running` https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html

Comment: thank you @Gorgious

Comment: and the `@persistent` decorator if you want to include it in your addon and auto-run on file load https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example

Comment: very useful, thank you!